# LINQ Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am getting an error using the query below, using EF + LINQ

```
 var model = (from c in _db.Accounts
              let geo = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(c.Latitude.Value), Convert.ToDouble(c.Longitude.Value))
              where ((geo.GetDistanceTo(CurrentCoord) / 1000) < 3) 
              orderby c.Name
              select new CompanyVM
              {
                  Name = c.Name,
                  ... 
              }).ToList();
```

Runtime error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Can someone explain why it is failing?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework tries to translate your LINQ query into SQL query that can be executed against the database. Because of that you can't use `GeoCoordinate` in your query.

Even if the constructor worked `Convert.ToDouble` call would fail, because it can't be translated into SQL either.

You might want to look into using [Spatial Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx) in SQL and Entity Framework.

Or you might want to write your own version of [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (that's the one used by `GetDistanceTo` within your LINQ query. Entity Framework should handle math quite well.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can use GeoCoordinate & GetDistanceTo? thx

Comment: You'd have to get all your data from database into application memory and run your query as Linq to Objects query. You most likely don't want to do that.